# Angular and Firebase: How to setup Cloud Firestore Security Rules?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Let me ask you how to setup security rules in Cloud Firebase Console. I've studied official Firebase documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions?authuser=0 and this article https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/firestore-security-rules-guide/, but I'm not able to figure out behavior of security rules in my app.

**What's the problem?**

Firstly I'd like to start with very basic type of rules. I want to allow the user to access to products collection anyway and block access to orders collection if the user in unauthenticated (not logged in).

My rules looks like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /categories/{category} {
      allow read, write;
    }

    match /products/{product} {
      allow read, write, list, get, update;
    }

    match /orders/{order} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }

  }
}
```

**And how it works at this moment:**

- I'm able to read, write products collention only in my app's admin
  panel (so I can mange products) but on customer side, products are
  blocked. In Firebase Console this rule passed the test (see screanshot) but in dev
  console I can see a message: "Missing or insufficient permissions".
  10 minutes went by and the result is the same. And it's unclear for
  me, because I've setup a rule to allow access to products anytime (line no. 9).
- second problem is, if I test orders collention I have an error
  "Error: simulator.rules line [13], column [29]. Null value error (see screanshot).

[image: products collection test result]
[image: orders collection test result]
So, would you mind to help fix the foregoing issues?

Additional usefull inforation:

- Angular6 | Firebase 5.2.0 | AngularCLI 6.0.8 | Authentication method via
  Google

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

In the simulator, you have not turned on the 'Authenticated' toggle. Once you turn that on, the request passed will have auth values. Currently, it is null and therefore you are getting an error trying to access the Orders collection.